# Call function from outside a class

Tags: php, class, function

I am trying to call a function from outside a class and having problems:

```
class Factorial{

    public function factorial($number) {
        if ($number < 2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return ($number * factorial($number-1));
        }
    }
}

$f = new Factorial();
echo $f->factorial(5);
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much

Comment: Also note that the method factorial() will be called when creating the object: because it has the same name as the class itself it's treated as Constructor method. (If you enable notices and error display it'll show missing and undefined errors for $number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not outside, but inside:

```
public function factorial($number) {
    if ($number < 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return ($number * $this->factorial($number-1));
    }
}
```

If you want to refer to another method you have to use `$this->methodname` where `$this` refers the instance:

> The pseudo-variable `$this` is available when a method is called from within an object context. `$this` is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs (...))

I suggest to read [*PHP - OOP - The Basics*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Answer (score 2):

`$this->factorial($number-1)` is what you want to call the class method. The code is getting confused because you named the class the same thing as the function (and it thinks it's a constructor).

Comment: Thank you Michael, you absolutely right. I have changed the name of the class and everything went smoothly. :D